# Objective-C crash on appending array to textview's text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview

I'm newer to Objective-C though I have worked in Java, C, and C++ and I'm still learning Objective-C.

I have a socket, a receive data function, and a text view. As data comes in, I want to append it to the text view. Now my textview has some pre-populated text at the start. If in every call to receieve data that data comes in, I just get the current text of the text view, append it to itself in a `nsstring` with:

```
 NSString *oldtext = [mTextViewAlias text];
 NSString *toSend = [oldtext stringByAppendingString: oldtext];
```

and then set the text view to `toSend`,  it works fine, and I see the data grow in my text view.

The problem is, I want to append:

```
 UInt8 buffer[len]; // which has data from the socket. len is set to amount of data on each call of receive data as follows
 int len = CFDataGetLength(df);
```

What I've been trying to do is convert a buffer to a `nsstring` and append. for example:

```
NSString *newdata = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: buffer];
```

it's occurred to me that buffer may not terminate with a `'\0'` character so I've even created a new buffer called char `newbuffer[len+1];` and copied buffer into it and added a `\0` as the last character.

I can append the first time around on the first pass of new data, but the second append, appending to something that had chars from buffer appended to the text once before always crashes.

I did a little trick where `if len > 10 assign buffer[10]='\0'`.  And it actually let me grab data twice before crashing the third time.

It seems I have one of two problems and I'm not sure how to fix it.  One is I can only grab as much data as is in the buffer and somehow these `nsstring`s are depending on it and when I change the buffer when receiving data, it is called again it causes the crash. Or maybe it's just still an issue with the `'\0'` not being there still though I don't see how.

Comment: You might have better luck using a NSMutableData class as your buffer instead of a pure C array. When I program for Obj-C I try to keep it all Obj-C as the conversions can get a little hairy. I'll have to look up the documentation on some things and then I might have an actual answer for you

Comment: do you mind showing the code and/or function that is receiving the data from the socket? Do you only receive it as a C array? I'm also assuming you aren't just getting data from a URL as there are really nice functions in the API to do that automagically for you.

Comment: It's a socket more like telnet. the connection is for a chat and game server but its got some formats you can turn on to organize the raw feed but then its still sending raw text i just know how to organize it better with formats.  got something like this:CFDataGetBytes(df, range, buffer);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSMutableData *buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[buffer appendBytes:aCArray length:lengthOfaCArray];
NSString *newdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: buffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//When your finished with newdata and buffer, dont forget to release it
//This might be done automatically if you have Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) on
[newdata release];
[buffer release];
```

Full reference on the encoding types [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE).
No guarantees this works as I wrote this code from a Windows machine and a couple tabs open at Apple's developer site. But should help you in the right direction.

Comment: I tried to follow that as follows:     char buffer2[len];
    for(int a=0; a<len; a++)
       buffer2[a]=buffer[a];
  
    NSMutableData *buffer3 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [buffer3 appendBytes:buffer2 length:len];
    NSString *newdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: buffer3 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    
    
    //if(len > 10)
      //  newbuffer[10]='\0';
   
   // NSString *newdata = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: newbuffer];
   NSString *toSend = [oldtext stringByAppendingString: newdata];

Comment: without lines that are commented out that's:   char buffer2[len];
    for(int a=0; a<len; a++)
       buffer2[a]=buffer[a];
  
    NSMutableData *buffer3 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [buffer3 appendBytes:buffer2 length:len];
    NSString *newdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: buffer3 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];    
    
      NSString *toSend = [oldtext stringByAppendingString: newdata];

Comment: want to add that with just: NSString *newdata = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: newbuffer]; And i just set the textfield to the current data  ( lose the history) it does work fine. with my original method it seems multiple appends of new data, beyond the first, crash it.

Comment: no i'm wrong you appear to be right.  Got it working. apparently toward the end of my crashes i somehow created a break point. deleted that and ran the code you gave and it worked. my only question now is when to free. i'll try freeing both at end of function and see if that works.  i do have automatic reference counting. thanks Mike

Comment: You should be fine releasing (freeing) both at the end of the function. When you assign the textfield an NSString it should copy the value to its own variable. Also if you are only going to use the data once, and don't need a mutable version you can use something like `NSData *buffer3 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cArray length:len];` may want to look that up as I might not have it perfect on the parameters, Xcode autocomplete is good about it though. I think ARC will take care of the memory management for you so you don't have to worry about releasing, not an expert on ARC tho